# Prestashop 1.7 getting redirected from back office

Tags: nginx, virtual-machine, homestead, prestashop-1.7

As the title says, I am getting redirect from the back office of Prestashop 1.7 whenever I try to access one of the subpages. However, I can access some of the pages, but when I try to access the Advanced>Preferences or Modules pages, it redirects me to the main page.

I am running the project through Homestead(Ubuntu) VM from Windows.

My guess is that the issue is with nginx config file. Could someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
> server {

    # Ipv4
    listen 80;

    # IPv6
    # listen [::]:80;   

    # SSL Ipv4 & v6
    # listen 443 ssl;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl;

    # ssl_session_timeout 24h;
    # ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    # ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    # ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+3DES:RSA+3DES:AES128-SHA:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;
    # ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    # Do not forget to create this file before with OpenSSL : "openssl dhparam -out /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem 2048"
    # ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem;

    # Your domain names here
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    #Your website root location
    root /Code/PrestaShopMarket/;  

    # Your admin folder
    set $admin_dir /admin3085ixto1;

    # Gzip Settings, convert all types.
    gzip on;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;

    # Can be enhance to 5, but it can slow you server
    # gzip_comp_level    5;
    # gzip_min_length    256;

    gzip_types
        application/atom+xml
        application/javascript
        application/json
        application/ld+json
        application/manifest+json
        application/rss+xml
        application/vnd.geo+json
        application/vnd.ms-fontobject
        application/x-font-ttf
        application/x-web-app-manifest+json
        application/xhtml+xml
        application/xml
        font/opentype
        image/bmp
        image/svg+xml
        image/x-icon
        text/cache-manifest
        text/css
        text/plain
        text/vcard
        text/vnd.rim.location.xloc
        text/vtt
        text/x-component
        text/x-cross-domain-policy;
        # Supposed to be the case but we never know
        # text/html;

    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";

    # Symfony controllers
    location ~ /(international|_profiler|module|product|feature|attribute|supplier|combination|specific-price)/(.*)$ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args $admin_dir/index.php$is_args$args;     
    }


    # Redirect needed to "hide" index.php
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$uri&$args;

        # Old image system ?
        rewrite ^/([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$1$2$3.jpg last;
        rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$1$2$3$4.jpg last;
        rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$1$2$3$4$5.jpg last;
        rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$1$2$3$4$5$6.jpg last;
        rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7.jpg last;
        rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8.jpg last;
        rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9.jpg last;
        rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$8/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9$10.jpg last;
        rewrite ^/c/([0-9]+)(-[.*_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/c/$1$2$3.jpg last;
        rewrite ^/c/([a-zA-Z_-]+)(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/c/$1$2.jpg last;

    }


    location /admin3085ixto1/ {                           #Change this to your admin folder
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/.*$ /admin3085ixto1/index.php last; #Change this to your admin folder
    }
}

    error_page 404 /index.php?controller=404;

    # Static assets delivery optimisations
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=31536000;

    # Cloudflare / Max CDN fix
    location ~* \.(eot|otf|ttf|woff|woff2)$ {
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    }

    location ~* \.(css|js|docx|zip|pptx|swf|txt|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|webp|flv|ico|pdf|avi|mov|ppt|doc|mp3|wmv|wav|mp4|m4v|ogg|webm|aac)$ {
      expires max;
      log_not_found off;
      add_header Pragma public;
      add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
    }

    # Deny access to .htaccess .DS_Store .htpasswd etc
    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
    }

    # PHP 7 FPM part
    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {

        fastcgi_index index.php;

        # Switch if needed
        # include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        include fcgi.conf;

        # Do not forget to update this part if needed
        # fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;  
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;

        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_keep_conn on;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 30s;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 30s;

        # In case of long loading or 502 / 504 errors
        # fastcgi_buffer_size 256k;
        # fastcgi_buffers 256 16k;
        # fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
        client_max_body_size 10M;

        # Temp file tweak
        fastcgi_max_temp_file_size 0;
        fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;

   }

   # Allow access to robots.txt but disable logging every access
   location = /robots.txt {
       allow all;
       log_not_found off;
       access_log off;
   }


   # Prevent injection of php files in directories a user can upload stuff
   location /upload {
       location ~ \.php$ { deny all; }
   }
   location /img {
       location ~ \.php$ {  deny all;}
   }

   # Ban access to source code directories
   location ~ ^/(app|bin|cache|classes|config|controllers|docs|localization|override|src|tests|tools|translations|travis-scripts|vendor)/ {
      deny all;
   }

   # Banned file types
   location ~ \.(htaccess|yml|log|twig|sass|git|tpl)$ {
       deny all;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to switch to apache instead of nginx and use PHP7.0 to do so use below code in your Homestead.yaml file (remember to change domain and path)

```
- map: presta.shop
  to: /home/vagrant/htdocs/prestashop_1.7.3.3
  php: "7.0"
  type: apache
```

after that halt vagrant:

```
vagrant halt
```

and reload with provision - will take some time:

```
vagrant reload --provision
```

this should help - it does for me

**EDIT**

In PS version: 1.7.6.7 i was forced to uncoment those two lines in `.htaccess` located in admin folder:

```
     RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
     RewriteRule ^index\.php(/(.*)) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]
```

Before that for links like: `http://presta17.shop/admin466vvxojo/improve/modules/manage?_token=ZrnM85TEsROusexXinPySyjZQghmfHO7d7sSFI3Tgm4`
with `/index.php/` i get only: `Access denied.`